# How do we differentiate an integral with a different argument

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let's say we have:

$$y = \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$$

and we want $dy/dx$.

Do we consider $t$ as being $x$?

Comment: err i meant dy/dx

Comment: Refer to Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Ditto what Gladstone said.  Got a calc book?  Look it up.  And the answer to your last question is "no".

Comment: Would it be different if 0 was 2x instead?

Comment: @GladstoneAsder: Yes of course since you get :
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac 1h\left[\int_{2x+2h}^{x+h} e^{t^2} dt-\int_{2x}^{x} e^{t^2} dt\right]=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac 1h\left[\int_x^{x+h} e^{t^2} dt-\int_{2x}^{2x+2h} e^{t^2} dt\right]\\=e^{x^2}-2\;e^{(2x)^2}$$ (you have to subtract at the bottom, $t\mapsto 2x$ and the interval is doubled!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Let $$y = \int^x_a f(t) dt$$
if we know the anti-derivative of $f$ is $F$, then by fundamental theorem of calculus
$$
y = F(x) - F(a)
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}F(x) - \frac{d}{dx}F(a) = \frac{d}{dx}F(x) = f(x).
$$

Answer (score 3):

Shortly yes. Longer derivation :

\begin{align}
y'(x):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}h&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac 1h\left[\int_0^{x+h} e^{t^2} dt-\int_0^{x} e^{t^2} dt\right]\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac 1h\int_x^{x+h} e^{t^2} dt\\
&=e^{x^2}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = e^{x^2}$ by a direct use of FTC. Note that $t$ is a dummy variable.

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220923/integration-differentiation/220936#220936).
$$ y(x+h)-y(x) = \int_0^{x+h} e^{t^2} dt - \int_0^{x} e^{t^2} dt $$

$$ =  \int_0^{x} e^{t^2} dt + \int_{x}^{x+h} e^{t^2} dt - \int_0^{x} e^{t^2} dt $$

$$ \implies \frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h}= \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h} e^{t^2} dt $$

Take the limit of the above as $h\to 0$ and see what you get.

**Added:** For the sake of completion. To see that the limit is $e^{x^2}$, see this

$$ \Big| \frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h}-e^{x^2}  \Big|= \Big|\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h} e^{t^2} dt-\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h} e^{x^2} dt   \Big| $$

$$ =\Big| \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h} \left(e^{t^2}-e^{x^2}\right) dt  \Big|\leq \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}\Big| e^{t^2}-e^{x^2} \Big|dt $$

$$ < \epsilon \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h} dt = \epsilon. $$

Note that we used the continuity of the function on the interval $[x,x+h]$, that is

$$ |h|<\delta \implies \Big| e^{t^2}-e^{x^2} \Big|< \epsilon . $$

Answer (score 1):

In general we have by chain rule
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(  \int_{v(x)}^{u(x)} f(t) dt\right)=f\left(u(x)\right)\times u'(x)-f\left(v(x)\right)\times v'(x)$$